# Where is set the main/primary color value in Luma theme

Tags: magento2, theme, less-css, luma-theme

I'm trying to find out which is the file that sets the main blue color in Luma theme.

There is a blue defind @color-blue1: #1979c3; in lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_colors.less

Where Luma gets it from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luma inherits variables from

```
lib/web/css/source/lib/varibales/_buttons.less

@button-primary__background: @color-blue1;
@button-primary__border: 1px solid @color-blue1;

lib/web/css/source/lib/varibales/_typography.less
@link__color: @color-blue1;
@link__hover__color: @color-blue2;
@focus__color: @color-sky-blue1;
```

and other colors from lib and blank theme.

One have to overwrite all the variables in current store's theme, file `_theme.less` as Zach pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it comes from: `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source\_theme.less`

You should be able to override it in your theme with `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/web/css/source/_theme.less`

Read more [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html)

Comment: I don't see where blue is set in: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source/_theme.less